# Subdomain to folder in Plesk

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, subdomain, plesk

I use Plesk and I need to display the content of a folder in a subdomain.

I have the .htaccess file as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect HTTP and WWW to HTTPS without WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#Redirect subdomain to folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The first rules work correctly redirecting to the secure version with www. But the following rules don't work.

In the DNS records, I have created a CNAME record from sub.domain.com to domain.com, is this correct?

When accessing sub.domain.com from the browser, it redirects me to the Plesk login page (sub.domain.com/login_up.php), and any other files (existing in the folder) give a 404 error.

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm a web developer but I don't understand servers

Comment: Does Plesk not give you the option to create subdomains? Plesk should then create the necessary DNS (ie. `CNAME`) record(s) for you. It also needs to configure the server to accept requests to that subdomain. You should also be able to configure the subdomain so that it points directly to the `/sub` subdirectory - you should not have to rewrite the request in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Just to add, it looks like the step to configure the server to accept requests to that subdomain is perhaps missing? The server is not flat out rejecting the request, but it is routing the request to an area outside of the public HTML space. And I should say, that _depending on your requirements_ you should not have to rewrite the request in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite!! The solution, indeed, was to create a subdomain and point your hosting to the corresponding folder. Now I'll create the answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple.

You have to **create a subdomain** of the main domain in Plesk and, in the hosting options, point to the folder as follows:

```
/httpdocs/folder
```